# ClassNotFound exception with my JSP and servlet

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, servlets

I've encountered some problem when I using JSP and servlet to post json object. I use tomcat 6.0 and JDK 1.7.0_09. I think I included all the necessary jars. Here is the error information:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JsonParser  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> Jan 04, 2013 10:24:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet JsonParser
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JsonParser  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: which jar is JsonParser in, and is that jar included or on the classpath in any way?

Comment: How exactly are you building/deploying? Using commandline or an IDE? That `JsonParser`, is that the name of your servlet? Is it really in the default package as your `<servlet-class>` seems to have specified?

Comment: JsonParser is in the Java src folder, I use IDE(Eclipse) to deploy my project.this servlet (JsonParser) is in the default packages. I still don't know what is wrong, hmmm.

Comment: If you use *not* the default package?

Comment: I do use the default package. Do you mean that I should use a different package instead of the default one?

Comment: yes, always use correctly named packages.

Comment: was the packagename right? the reason could be: "In Tomcat 4.x and up, the JSP's package will never be the same
as the default package."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have named your packages properly, beacuse

> In Tomcat 4.x and up, the JSP's package will never be the same as the
>   default package.