# JodConverter application is not working in webapplication

Tags: java, servlets, http-post, openoffice.org, jodconverter

I am converting docx file to pdf file using JODconverter. The same code is working fine from standalnoe java application but its not working when I am using the same inside webapp and throwing

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet CmisWebClient threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeConnection
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.ap.cmis.web.CmisWebClient.doPost(CmisWebClient.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add information how and where you've installed the JODconverter jar in  the servlet container.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClassNotFound exception with my JSP and servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160191/classnotfound-exception-with-my-jsp-and-servlet)

Comment: @tohuwawohu I am using tomcat 6. Created a web application, adding dependency jar as user library.